# Configure IIS SMTP server to forward to more than one address

Tags: iis, smtp

I have the SMTP service installed on Server 2008 R2.  Under Domains, if I go to properties, under Route Domain, I have the option to forward all mail to smart host and I currently have one address [nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn].

Is it possible to have more than one address here?  ***[nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn];[nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn]*** or ***[nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn],[nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn]***?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read the RFCs for SMTP.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)  It will give you all the information you will need to know.  If you need more functionality than this, you'll need an email server.

Comment: This is not possible.  I spun up a VM and tried all combinations of separators I could think of (spaces, commas, semi colons etc) and they all displayed "Not a valid domain"

Comment: Exactly.  You're going to need a full email server to do what you want to do.